# twitter login button

Tags: django, google-app-engine

HI

I have a django application running on app engine and I want to add a twitter login to my application.

Do you have a good links how to do that. I already registered my app in twitter.

Just don't know how to do login/logout buttons.

Thanks, Arshavski Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to accept Twitter as a login is to take advantage of a service like [RPX](http://www.rpxnow.com/).

The app engine recipe website has code which demonstrates [how to integrate RPX with app engine](http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/accept-google-aol-yahoo-myspace-facebook-and-openid-logins/).

I also wrote a complete (but tiny) demo app which demonstrates this too.  You can get the code here: http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/tree/master/demo/.